# Windows 10 Search: Search my stuff by default

Tags: windows-10, search, cortana, windows-10-v1511

Generally I use the built-in Windows 10 search to find my documents by name. However, in Windows 10 version 1511 the search is not performed in my stuff. Is there a way to make "Search my stuff" the default search mode?

---

An example. Say I want to find a file named "Dates.xlsx". If I type "dates" into the search box, I see this:

[image]

Then I click "Search my stuff" and scroll to see the results in my documents:

[image]

But I'd like to see the second picture instead of the first one by default to search my files easier and faster.

P.S. Cortana isn't supported and is turned off in my region.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do except upgrade Windows 10. For example, in newer versions like the infamous Windows 10 version 1809, the search is better, and it includes your stuff by default, alongside system results like the one in your example. See my example below.[image]